# apache just tells me there is a syntax error when I reload the conf files

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I've been modifying my server's conf files and when I reload them, it just says there is an error, but it doesn't tell me where the error is.  Is there a log file this is recorded to? or how else could I know where the syntax error is coming from?

Comment: You can post your conf (without the comments)

Comment: What version of Apache, running on what operating system? `apachectl configtest` on stock 2.2.x should give you a message of the form `Syntax error on line [Line#] of [conf file]:`...

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, thanks for the responses though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight out of the Apache docs:

```
You can check your configuration files for syntax errors without starting the server by using apachectl configtest or the -t command line option.
```